# Does Here allow Clustering for Live Gps tracking data?

Tags: here-api, heremaps, here-maps-rest

Is there a way of doing clustering on HERE Maps for dynamic locations?

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/clustering/marker-clustering - there is only for Static.

We'd like it to have real-time fleet visibility but due to amount of vehicles its hard to work on it.

Anyone knows how to do it? Is it Supported?

We tried all:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/clustering/marker-clustering

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, the clustering on dynamic locations is not available so far, you can confirm this by checking the following example where this is only possible for static: https://github.com/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/tree/master/marker-clustering
Regards!